# problem with thunar after installing lxqt desktop

Tags: thunar, lxqt, pcmanfm

I have Debian 11 with xfce desktop.After i also installed lxqt desktop when i open the Thunar file manager it doesn't show two of my ntfs partitions in left panel.
‌‌‌But the partitions can be mounted via terminal.
And those partitions are not displayed in pcmanfm either.
Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I define these two lines in /etc/fstab and problem solved :

```
 UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     /media/sda5      ntfs    defaults         0 2
 UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     /media/sdb5      ntfs    defaults         0 2
```